# Code coverage and test results for .NET Core projects in VSTS

Tags: testing, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

How do we enable code coverage and test results for .NET Core projects in VSTS?

Currently, it is not enabled for a .NET Core test task.

Comment: Related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425936/how-to-measure-code-coverage-in-asp-net-core-projects-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio Test task with /framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1" option to run .NET Core tests. (Specify vstest.console.exe path in a Visual Studio Test task: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform)

An article about code coverage: *[Working with Code Coverage](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/analyze.md#coverage)*.

But there is the issue when uploading a coverage file: *[Publish VSTest: Skipping attachment as it exceeded the maximum allowed size or not available on disk](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/4666)*.

On the other hand, you may get an empty-result-generated issue: [Running code coverage from Visual Studio 2017 always results in "Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented.."](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/102973/running-code-coverage-from-vs-2017-always-results.html).

To conclude, you can track the update of these issues, and try again after the issues have been fixed.

Answer (score 4):

This is half an answer (as I'm not a fan of code coverage).

First get `dotnet test` to output a trx file with the test results by passing the arguments `-l trx`

[image: dotnet test]

Then follow it up with the Publish Test Results task.

Here are the options I used:

[image: publish test results]

And you will get your results (P.S. It's a very simple app):

[image: results]

I'm guessing that a similar approach for code coverage can be attained.