# Adding Code Coverage of .NET Core XUnit project to VSTS build

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, azure-devops, code-coverage, azure-pipelines

I'd like to add the code coverage metrics to our VSTS build.
The solution is ASP.NET core with XUnit.
Please advise on the steps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: At the top of the page clearly the information is provided.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting. Do you refer to this link? https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md

Comment: if yes, then point me how to enable code coverage for the .net core projects

Comment: Combining all keywords in the message, Google can easily lead you to threads like https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/579 Microsoft is still far from making everything ready.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code coverage and test results for dotnet core projects in VSTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159067/code-coverage-and-test-results-for-dotnet-core-projects-in-vsts)

Comment: I saw that link as well, however, my question is more relevant to XUnit rather than MSTests and besides there is no clear answer. In any case, there is no "At the top of the page clearly the information is provided". I'd prefer, someone knowledgeable from VSTS team answer my question

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Refer to these steps to enable code coverage for .NET Core XUnit test:

1. Edit projects’ files (test and related project) to add DebugType property

for example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

2. Update Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk package to latest version (change version value to [15.7.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/))
3. Add Visual Studio Test task to build definition and specify **Test assemblies** and **Search folder**
4. Choose **Specific location option in Select test platform using** section
5. Specify `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform` in **Path to vstest.console.exe**
6. Check **Code coverage enabled** option
7. Specify `/framework:".NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0"` in **Other console options** box

Comment: Thanks! I wonder if it works with Test assemblies should I "dotnet publish" first?

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Do not need.

Comment: You are right about no need to publish. However, it doesn't work:Data collector 'Code Coverage' message: Cannot find CodeCoverage.exe.. FileNotFoundException: No test is available in C:\agent\_work\2\s\test\MyProj.UnitTests\obj\release\netcoreapp2.0\MyProj.UnitTests.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

Comment: I do have <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="15.7.0" />

Comment: What're tasks of your build definition? Can you share the detail log on the OneDrive? (Set system.debug variable to true, then queue build and share this log) Try to specify` **\*UnitTest*.dll
!**\obj\**` (two lines) in Test assemblies input box.

Comment: Can I email you the link to OneDrive?

Comment: What's the result if you build it through Hosted VS 2017 agent? Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? if so, you can share the sample project on the OneDrive.

Comment: So, the Coverage works with the Hosted Build! (I've uploaded the logs to onedrive). So, what could be the problem with the on-prem agent? One difference is our on-prem build has Professional VS installed.

Comment: @BorisLipschitz Visual Studio Enterprise version is needed.

Comment: Oh my gosh! To create code coverage in VSTS you have to use VS2017 Enterpise... I would have hoped that code coverage of VSTS isn't dependant on the version of the installed IDE...

Comment: It's a bit of waste of money to use VS Enterprise edition to run on a build server... :)

Comment: @BorisLipschitz VS enterprise version is required, but you can use Hosted Agent.

Comment: No, we have on-prem build and I don't want to waste the Enterprise licence for the Build Server

Comment: For this scenario, you need to use Hosted Agent.

Comment: Hosted Agent is out of the question, as my Integration tests require resources that are not available on the Hosted Agent

Comment: What's the result if you install VS enterprise without licence on build server?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT what does `<DebugType>Full</DebugType>` do? Is it safe if I enable this for a package that will get published on Nuget?