# Azure DevOps SourceLink and Symbol Server with Release DLL in Nuget package

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package, symbol-server, sourcelink

I have a .NET Standard 2.0 `TestSouceLink` project with the following configuration in the `.csproj`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
    <Authors>Jérôme MEVEL</Authors>
    <Description>Just a test package for SourceLink</Description>
    <Version>1.1.1</Version>

    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SourceLink.Vsts.Git" Version="1.0.0-beta2-18618-05">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

We have an Azure DevOps server which generates our Nuget packages in build pipelines.

I added a `Publish symbols path` task at the end to push the `.pdb` files to the Symbol Server and I managed to get Source Link to work along with the Azure DevOps Symbol Server with the **Debug** build configuration only.

The problem is that I don't want my DLLs in the Nuget packages to be generated in Debug mode. I want them to be **Release**. But when I change the `dotnet pack` task to use `Release` in the `Configuration to package` text box, then Source Link doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to generate a Nuget package with a Release DLL inside? and to still have Source Link working with the Symbol Server?

I don't mind using a `.nuspec` file along with the `Nuget` CLI if this is the only way however I don't want to include the `.pdb` files inside the Nuget packages.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try leaving the `DebugType` as `portable` instead of `full`? The default is `portable`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46904359/23059

Comment: Ok so after some tests it seems changing it back to `portable` (with `Debug` configuration) doesn't work with (up-to-date) VS 2017 but works with VS 2019. In any case it doesn't work in `Release` configuration. Thanks for the link, I didn't know about that

Comment: Have you tried disabling Debug -> Options -> General "Enable Just My Code" option?  I believe this should make it work with Release configuration