# .net core coverage results not displaying

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm trying to figure out how to show Coverage in TFS. with .net CORE.

Below is my build definition.  I have a "Test .NET Core" task.

[image: tfsbuilddef]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?tabs=netcore21

From above url, I found this hint:

> Run the tests in the project in the current directory and generate a
>   test results file in the trx format:
>
> dotnet test --logger:trx

And I have test results working.

(Details of Test-Task and the Publish-Test-Results below)

Publish Test Results (task).
With the following arguments

Test Result Format:
VSTest

Test Results Files
**/*.trx

So I can see Test Results :) (below image)

[image: tfs build succeeded]

But how do you get Code Coverage working? (above image, red circle...there is a place holder for Coverage)

What I've tried:

There is a "Coverage" task..but doesn't seem right to me. (image below)

[image: faux coverage task]

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio Enterprise installed on the build machine?

Comment: Hi.  I don't "own" the build machine.  I will find out.  Is this a magic button? :)

Comment: The Code Coverage works only in Visual Studio Enterprise..

Comment: I kinda understand you.  But the TFS Build Machine has a place holder for it.  (My screen shots).  Are you saying the TFS-Build-Machine placeholder relies on VS Studio Ent on the build machine?  That's seems weird to me.  (  Yes, I do understand that DEVELOPERS need VS-2017-Enterprise to see coverage while developing).

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for that problem?

Comment: @Andre.  The short answer  is "no".  HOWEVER, if you follow my answer at the url I  provide in this comment and follow one of the URL that I mention.. IIRC, there is a person who got "reportgenerator" working on the build machine.  (My answer to this other question is about using it locally).   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425936/how-to-measure-code-coverage-in-asp-net-core-projects-in-visual-studio/55271781#55271781